# Fastest way to import the table with > 20 milion rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table which I need to migrate from one server to another (Amazon Aurora). I made a sql dump and downloaded it to my PC. It is about 4.7 GB. To import this dump into new server will take about 6.5 hours which is too long. Is there a way to do it faster? Maybe to import from server to server? Table is InnoDB.

Comment: Please update with what you are currently doing to import the dump.

Comment: I'm using HeidiSQL and I try to load SQL directly (from PC to (Amazon) server).

Comment: You can check the answer here:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster